# Extract value from specific flow file content in Nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have a flow which runs few scripts and provide an output like below:

```json
{
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": "3599",
  "ext_expires_in": "3599",
  "expires_on": "1696064476",
  "not_before": "1696060576",
  "resource": "https://management.com/",
  "access_token": "kVSiwZy0pwnXRbakA98b_pxQRHyjdF5jkXBcGtRdPtGlEn8GbvplFQM_8PtDKLdvHydhU3gRSDd_t22OfN3wiGyY9Rfiw3SL6sR4VdPseaOerrQq5Hx8yaqZQkbYL1OfsNieTUV31WM1ymxhbYLkgxjbao2EpzC1XbZX_6jnjPnA66lZIBw"
}
```

> ```
> https://crtyu.net/ars/98d3-99c48f0c0165?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=6nakoARUgAhttps&st=2023-09-30T07%3A57%3A02Z&se=2023-09-30T2A02%3A02Z&sp
> ```

```json
{
  "url": "https://ccswindows.net/armrep/fda8053c-2-466d-98d3-99c48f0c0165?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=6nakgAJ6f2%2BL1Lhdf%2BcksTxefYX7TDpf53%2B4UXo%3D&spr=https&st=2023-09-30T07%3A57%3A02Z&se=2023-09-30T20%3A02=r",
  "subscription": "c544",
  "is_billing_completed": true,
  "from_date": "2023-03-01",
  "to_date": "2023-03-02",
  "cost_type": "AmortiCost"
}
```

Kafka topic for producer is amortized_billing
Cost Queued

from this response I only want the **'url'** which I need to invoke to generate a file.
Need help in fetching the url as an attribute.

Comment: Hi Ram, there are three different urls starting with `https`, one in middle is already apart from a JSON value. Which one do you want to extract from the rest of them, and in which shape or format ? Btw, why there are two JSON ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Hi, Actually we are getting response through an API which provides a bearer token as a 1st JSON and in the 2nd JSON we will have the url , which we will hit to generate a file , the one in the middle can be ignore,I just want to fetch the 'url' which is in 2nd JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a ***JoltTransformJSON*** processor along with the following specification :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "url": ""
    }
  }
]
```

which will extract **url** value only.

Comment: Hi @Ram , can you please upvote also as only upvoting increments the tag badge, thanks in advance.